# Android NDK test directive value

Tags: android, android-ndk, preprocessor, directive

I have an Android project, using Android NDK.

In file **Application.mk**, I use a custom directive named **MYDIRECTIVE** :

```
APP_CFLAGS := -DMYDIRECTIVE=TEST
```

And in .cpp file, I would like test its value :

```
#ifdef MYDIRECTIVE
#if MYDIRECTIVE == 'TEST'
/* do some stuff */
#else
#error MYDIRECTIVE is unknown
#endif
#endif
```

And the issue is that I get **MYDIRECTIVE is unknown** message.

When I compile with **V=1** option, I see directive in compilation :

```
 -MYDIRECTIVE=TEST
```

I tried test with **'TEST'**, with **TEST**, with **"TEST"**, and I still get error.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use  `#if` directive to check for string equality. As said [in the GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html):

> The `#if' directive allows you to test the value of an **arithmetic**
>   expression.

Anyway in C, you don't compare strings by using `==` but by using `strcmp()`. And the preprocessor cannot use `strcmp()`.

Maybe you might want to use `MYDIRECTIVETEST` instead:

```
#ifdef MYDIRECTIVETEST
/* do some stuff */
#else
#error MYDIRECTIVETEST is unknown
#endif
```